# Conflicting Modrewrite Rules

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

As my previous questions may already show you, I am not great with modrewrite. I have tried to search and come up empty for this particular issue. I hope that someone can assist me with fixing this up;

I am using modrewrite as part of a Short URL generator, accessing the unique ID directly will forward them to their destination. adding /v on to the end will allow a portal page that will display the URL they are being forwarded to (Like a Preview Page)

Because the /v comes after the ID, it works just fine, however I want to allow for new pages to be added via **$_GET**

**This is the shortcut link being given to users;**

```
javascript:void(location.href='http://www.website.com/n/?url='+location.href)
```

**This is the content of the .htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^n actions.php?do=new [NS,L,NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ actions.php?id=$1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$  actions.php?id=$1&do=$2 [NC]
```

**The Problem:**
because **/n** is in place of the ID, it obviously conflicts. I have tried NS and L because they are able to stop execution after the rule is matched. Upon further inspection, they of course dont work as well as I would like.

Finally, here are some examples of how the URL's are desired to look in the final product;

```
   New Submission:
http://www.web.com/n/?url=http://www.google.com      [Outputs new URL as 12345]
   Visit the ID directly:
http://www.web.com/1A2b34D5                       [Forwards to URL Destination]
   Visit the ID Preview Link:
http://www.web.com/1A2b34D5/v             [Displays preview, Delayed Forwarder]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the `url` variable from the query string just add [`QSA`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa) to the options and it will save the url in `$_GET['url']`

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f   # if the url file does not exist
RewriteRule ^n/?$ actions.php?do=new [NS,L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ actions.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$  actions.php?id=$1&do=$2 [NC,L]
```

Also in your actions.php you have to put conditions:

```
if (isset($_GET['do']))
{
    if ($_GET['do'] == 'new') // http://www.web.com/n/?url=http://www.google.com
    {
        if (!isset($_GET['url'])) die('No url');

        // save the url
        // and outputs new URL
    }
    else if ($_GET['do'] == 'v') // http://www.web.com/1A2b34D5/v
    {
        // Visit the ID Preview Link
    }
}
else // http://www.web.com/1A2b34D5
{
    // Visit the ID directly
}
```

**EDIT:**

I don't know what it's going on but like I said in my comment I've tested in my localhost and it works as you expected, in my tests I have a `test.php` with this content `var_dump($_GET);` even I've created an `actions.php` file with the same content and here are some url examples that I've tested:

**Example1:**

`http://localhost/n?url=google.com` or
`http://localhost/n/?url=google.com`

This rule was executed:

`RewriteRule ^n/?$ actions.php?do=new [NS,L,NC,QSA]`

Output:

`array(2) { ["do"]=> string(3) "new" ["url"]=> string(10) "google.com" }`

**Example2:**

`http://localhost/n12345` Output: `array(1) { ["id"]=> string(6) "n12345" }`
`http://localhost/nnnn456` Output: `array(1) { ["id"]=> string(6) "nnnn456" }`

This rule was executed:

`RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ actions.php?id=$1 [NC,L]`

**Example3:**

`http://localhost/n12345/v` Output: `array(2) { ["id"]=> string(6) "n12345" ["do"]=> string(1) "v" }`

This rule was  executed:

`RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$  actions.php?id=$1&do=$2 [NC,L]`

Comment: The strings offered will include lower, upper and numeric values in a mixed assortment. That is simply a example, which currently does work. I apologize for being vague and will adjust accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for that, but the problem still exists that it thinks that /n is a URL that it needs to redirect. example (Database offline) www.agn.im/n/?url=http://www.google.com/

Comment: I'm testing right now in my localhost and it works, can you paste the content of actions.php in pastebin.com? There is something wrong with your code or do you have only these rules on .htaccess?

Comment: Nothing to do with the php file, its in a redirect loop because the first rule conflicts with the additional rule because it thinks that n is a code that the second rule should be handling. The code I provided is the entire htaccess, I am not running additional rules on it.

Comment: answer updated! I have tested in your server `actions.php` and `functions.php` and there is a redirect loop but with `test.php` there is no redicect loop, it's weird

Comment: I will test tonight when I get back to my terminal. test.php is very different so it would work after all. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Ok, So I got it working with your original code, that is without the RewriteCond. With it I simply get an error 500. However, ANY string starting with n will force it to go to ?do=new :(

Comment: test added in the answer, it's weird, when you get the 500 server error it means that there is something wrong in the `.htaccess` file, like a symbol or char/s